# Autosetting foreign key Ids for child objects in WebApi Rest actions bound for EFCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm a little bit new to Dotnet core WebApi and Entity Framework so forgive me if I'm missing something super obvious.

I have web API PUT methods to update a model on its own, or as a child of a parent - by submitting the full model of the parent with a child.

The problem I've run into is that I have marked the foreign key ID as Required using DataAnnotations [Required] plus [Range] because, without it, a child level PUT would be worthless. But I would like to accept it without the parent ID specified if it's attached to the parent in the JSON.

For example:

For class

```
public class ParentData
{ 
    public id id {get; set;}
    public string parentProperty {get; set;}
    public ChildData childData {get; set;}
}

public class ChildData
{
    public int childId {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public int parentId {get; set;}
    public string anotherAttribute{get; set;}
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ParentData parentData {get; set;}

}
```

This might be fine:

```
{
    "childId":123,
    "parentId":234,
    "anotherAttribute":"Bar"
}
```

But this will fail because parentId is missing:

```
{
    "id":234,
    "parentProperty":"Foo",
    "childData": 
    {
       "childId":"123",
       "anotherAttribute":"Bar"
    }
}
```

Given that I have a fluent EF Map (entityTypeBuilder().HasOne.WithOne().HasForeignKey()) is there a way I can just have the parent ID set automatically allowing the model to be considered valid?

I was thinking I could do something inside the SET operation for the ChildData object which probably comes before the model validation in the pipeline, but that seems overwrought compared to EF Mapping and Data Annotation.

Am I doomed to either set the properties manually or build a custom validator and not use data annotations here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Maybe you should separate API Models and EF Models.

In API you can remove Id property for Create operations or you can make it optional. Also for Update operations, you can make it `Required`

So in your example you'll need several more models.

`ParentData`  => implements CreateParentData and Id is required

`CreateParentData` => Id is optional

`ChildData` => implements CreateChildData and Id is required

`CreateChildData`  => Id is optional

You can use AutoMapper to map to your EF Entities.

**Option 2**

Implementing `IValidatableObject` interface in your models is an option. You can type your own validator.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

     // Do validation here, if there are errors add to the results

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that might get me a bit further; however the models seem to be validated inside out. That is, the ChildData model is validated before the ParentData has even finished deserializing. Also since the EF mapping hasn't happened yet the ChildData.parentData reference is null.

One thing that does seem to work is if I do a custom setter on ParentData.childData; then I can do something like:
`set {
    if (value.parentId>=0) {  value.parentId=this.id; }
    _childData = value;
}`

However this relies on a linear deserialization where Id comes before ChildData in the JSON

Comment: Maybe I couldn't explain myself correctly. I think you should not expect EF mapping in API part. I created a sample project. I didn't run it but pretty sure it will help you :)

Can you check this github [link](https://github.com/dnzz/api-model-example)